# Android - ListView with images scrolls too slow even without any processing in adapter's getView method

Tags: android, performance, image, listview

I am trying to create a list of people using Listview/customadapter. The rows show up pretty fast but scrolling is very slow even on a reasonably fast device. I tried several suggestions except using asynchtask hoping to have that as a last resort but nothing seems to improve the performance. Finally as a last shot before using asynchtask i tried to remove all processing in the adapter's getview method. Now all it does is inflate the view from an xml and display blank rows. I noticed that even then the scrolling speed hasnt improved. So i suspect the cause might be the structure of my layout.
    Is there any change i can do in it to make it faster ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/mId" android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"></TextView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/phone" android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_width="0px"></TextView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/email" android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_width="0px"></TextView>


<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/bl_row_bg"></ImageView>


<TextView android:paddingTop="9.7dp" android:id="@+id/name"
    android:paddingLeft="25.88dp" android:text="xxxx"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_height="110dp" android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" android:paddingTop="6.47dp"
    android:paddingBottom="6.47dp" android:paddingRight="6.47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/txt1" android:paddingLeft="25.88dp"
    android:text="Turning 24" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/txt2" android:paddingLeft="25.88dp"
    android:text="23 Days to go" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"></TextView>

<ImageView android:layout_height="64.7dp" android:src="@drawable/ss_image2"
    android:id="@+id/image2" android:layout_width="64.7dp"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/bl_date_background"
    android:id="@+id/datebg" android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datebg" android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon1" android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon2" android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon4" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon3"
    android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon4" android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/date" android:text="Tue, Dec 12"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center" android:visibility="invisible"></TextView>
```

Comment: Is this your listitem xml layout?

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 5):

Try following

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT); // not sure if this is required for you. 
lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you consult the actual Android documentation first and compare the Java methods with the Android XML attributes:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

For those that need optimization in XML attributes:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:scrollingCache="false" />
```

Comment: Why android:scrollingCache="false" ?

Comment: Collecting scrolling cache may cause older phones to be slower. This is an XML snippet I've used in my applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make the ImageView asynchronous by using [WebImageView](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/)

I also noted (as @Abid states) that calling lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false); improves scrolling.  I had a ListView that was running fine on a Galaxy Tab 7" and which was awfully slow on a Galaxy Tab 10.1".  The reason was the memory allocation needed for the cache (and the need to grow the heap).

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own adapter to deal with the list view items I would have a map of `Drawables` that you can keep reference to in the `Adapter`. Chances are the issue is that each time the list view adapter is getting each child view for the list view it is having to load that image each time. It would be more performant to load those into memory before hand and then just reference them.